# Fetch csv data from a remote url with Node and Express

Tags: node.js, csv, express, url, fetch

I am sitting with an assignment where I am asked to fetch a remote url containing a csv-file from the backend to display some data in the frontend. I have never fetched anything from the backend before, so I don't really understand how this is done.

I've tried with the node-fetch library but it throws an error when I try to fetch saying that the url/file contains an invalid json response body.

I also tried converting the csv file to a hardcoded json file (and adding it to a folder called: 'data' in the backend) - and this works (I get the response in the terminal), but as this is not what they ask me to do in the assignment I want to find another solution.

There is a library called fast-csv that could help parse, but first I have to understand properly how to do the fetch from the backend I think. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You get this error as the resulting data from the fetch is not JSON. Consider replacing

`res => res.json()`

with

`res => res.text()`

Comment: To be clear, I understand that it is not JSON. But there is a package "fast-csv" in the backend that should take care of the parsing.

Comment: In other words, the answer did not tell me anything that I did not already know.